# When I tried to image, image is broken

Tags: reactjs, typescript

BASE_URL I want to fetch is composed like this.

```
{
  "renderings": [
    {
      "_id": "image_file"
    },
    ...more _id
}
```

I write the code like this, react+typescript

```
interface GalleryProps {
  _id: string;
}

interface GalleriesProps {
  renderings: GalleryProps[];
}

function Gallery() {
  const [gallery, setGallery] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchGallery() {
      const response = await fetch(BASE_URL);
      const result: GalleriesProps = await response.json();
      setGallery(result.renderings);
    }
    fetchGallery();
  }, []);

  return <div>{gallery && <img src={gallery} alt="gallery" />}</div>;
}
```

But Image is broken...
[image]

[image]

What should I do..?
I googled a lot for reference.

Comment: please try to load the image on our browser let see what you get

Comment: i think you're not serving data correctly

Comment: Should I have to download all image?

Comment: no ! can you share what you get from apis

Comment: You are setting array to ```setGallery(result.renderings);```
you must set setGallery(result.renderings[0]._id);

Comment: It seems difficult to share as it is a company project.

Comment: @EgorPashko Thanks a lot! 
Should I use a `map` to load all images?

Comment: Yes, try to follow, (setGallery(result.renderings) <- set all array
```
return   <div>{gallery && gallery.map((x) => <img alt="gallery" src={x._id} />)}</div>

```

Comment: How kind of you :)